# I get this error vlog-13069

Tags: verilog, modelsim

First of all, sorry for my English skills.

I am studying Verilog and I have this code

```
module paralelo_serie ( data_in,clk,  D_serie, nSyn, Done );
input wire [12:0] data_in;
input clk;
output reg D_serie, nSyn, Done;
genvar i;

84 if (data_in == 0) Done= 1;
else....
```

When I try to compile this code, I get this error message:

> Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Users/Pedro/Documents/master/asignaturas/primer cuatrimestre/Metodologia de diseño y herramientas cad/proyecto digital/proyecto digital.v(84): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '='.
>
> Error: C:/Users/Pedro/Documents/master/asignaturas/primer cuatrimestre/Metodologia de diseño y herramientas cad/proyecto digital/proyecto digital.v(84): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'Done'. Is there a missing '::'?

I am a beginner at this language and I don't know what happened. I get this error a few times in the code, but I can solve it sometimes by changing the reg to wire and other time change blocking assignment to no blocking... I don't really know how I can fix and really I am getting frustrated... please help, you are my last hope...

Sorry I forgotten, I use modelsim 10.4 student version

Comment: When do you want the `if (data_in == 0)` statement to be executed?

Answer (score 0):

AS toolic has mentioned the `84` looks like it was just an accidental cut and paste from your code.

If statements, unless they are for the generate statement need to be contained with in a process ( some call it a block ). This can be an `initial` or an `always`.

For combinatorial logic :

```
always @* begin
  if (data_in == 0) begin 
    Done = 'b1;
  end
  else begin
     Done = 'b0; 
    //...
  end
end
```

Not defining Done in the else branch will result in a latch being created.

While learning I would recommend using begin end statements and indenting code well as this helps clarify the structure of code and makes typos a bit easier to spot.

If `Done` was left as a wire you could just have used:

```
assign Done = (data_in == 0) ;
```

On the other hand if you wanted `Done` to be driven synchronously :

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (data_in == 0) begin 
    Done <= 'b1;
  end
  else begin
    //...
  end
end
```

Note the change to non-blocking (`<=`) assignments to correctly simulate a flip-flops behaviour. As Done is a full flip flop (stateful) then there is no need for the synthesis tool to add a latch if it is not specified in the else branch, it will just retain its value.